# Dispensing or dosing?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

As a non-native speaker I'm looking for the right term for a technical application/product that dispenses or doses a viscous liquid, i.e. the device will "output" a specific amount of "stuff".

However, dosing/dose/dosage appear to be "medical" to me, also maybe describing a ratio of components (like controlling the amount / rate of medicine/drug added to an IV drip).

On the other hand, dispenser more seems to be "outputting" or making available already discrete "entities", e.g. a tissue dispenser.

I'm lacking knowledge of more elaborate uses of those words and appreciate any comments.

- http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dispense#English
- http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dose#English

Comment: Check definition & usage applicable to the specific domain. In general English, *dispensing* focuses on the conveying part ('how', 'what') while *dosing* focuses on the quantitative aspect ('how much' 'at what rate').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two words are frequently used in a medical context, but can be applied elsewhere.

As you say, "dispensing" has more of a sense of "outputting".  A pharmacist may dispense a medicine, but that doesn't mean that the patient has taken it.

"Dosing" has more of a sense of "inputting".  A nurse giving a medicine to a patient would be "dosing".

Comment: Thanks, this is putting in words what I felt. As a follow-up question, what would you call the output, e.g. "amount"/"dose"/"portion"/"volume"?

Comment: "Dosing" is extensively used in the sense of 'outputting' as well. Think *dosing machine* search.google.com/search?q="dosing+machine"

Comment: @none, I would think you would *dispense a **volume** of liquid.*

Answer (score 4):

As the device outputs a viscous liquid, "dispense" seems to be an accurate term. The product can be compared to a soap dispenser. Therefore, I would suggest calling the product a

> -type of viscous liquid- dispenser

Answer (score 2):

Until just a few minutes ago, I was unware of the verb form *to dose*.

A quick Google Search brought me to the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosing) which explains that it is commonly used by engineers in thermal power stations, in water treatment, in steam industries, and chemical or textile plants.

If your intended audience does not work in any of those industries, I would avoid using *dose*.

As to your concern about dispenser, it is not limited to discrete amounts. In fact a quick Google Image [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dispenser&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=pCz6UfO-O8L4yQGj54DYAw&biw=1024&bih=768&sei=piz6Ud6EMajSyAHD94HQAw) for dispenser demonstrates that some of the most common types of dispensers are for water, liquid soap, and tape, each of which are not dispensed in discrete amounts.

Comment: Your answer illustrates the problem of using "quick Google searches" and "Wikipedia" in making deductions about other uses. Just because the examples of "dose" that you found relate to " thermal power stations, in water treatment, in steam industries, and chemical or textile plants" does **not** mean that it is not used in other areas. For example, you can give your garden plants the right *dose* of plant food; you should use the correct *dose* of weedkiller, etc.

Comment: Additionally, the fact that the most common types of dispensers maybe the ones you saw on an image search, does not mean that *all* dispensers dispense in non-discrete amounts. It depends on what the dispenser is dispensing - some dispensers *do* dispense discrete amounts. **Do not jump to conclusions about what words mean merely from the most popular Google results!!**

Comment: @TrevorD, I was referring to the use of dose as a verb, "to dose", perhaps that was unclear. "A dose" is certainly common as a noun, to give a dose, etc.

Comment: @TrevorD, I agree that google searches, wikipedia searches, etc. should not be the basis of one's conclusion, however, as evidence that a dispenser can be of non-discrete amounts, I feel it was pretty convincing. The meaning of "dispenser" is based on usage of the word. A google search can give an initial look into the words' usages...therefore its meaning. However, that should not replace native speaker familiarity with the word, dictionaries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm and provide further evidence that a **dispenser** is the word you are looking for. Moreover, the nozzle bit is commonly referred to as a [***pump dispenser***](http://www.photo-dictionary.com/phrase/9842/pump-dispenser.html).

[image]

The plastic container description in verbatim:

> The **dispenser bottles** are an ideal solution for liquid dispensing and
>   storage. **The pump** can be relocked by pushing down with a press pump
>   action for easy dispensing. The plastic lotion dispenser bottles are
>   suitable for shampoo, lotions, soap, sanitiser, creams and more.

definition of *nozzle* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nozzle